# Insertion if the record doesn't exist in the table using not exists in sql

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, not-exists

Well I only want to insert the data if it doesn't already exist in the table, if it exists nothing need to be done

```
insert into colleges (Id, Name, CreatedOn) values("20", "ASIET", "2017-12-14 
06:44:32") where not exists (select id from colleges where name = "ASIET")
```

I'm getting error

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'where not exists (select id from colleges where name = "ASIET")' at 
line 1
```

And thanx in advance for the help

Comment: You can't use where clauses for insert statement instead do this in your application code

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thanx, that was helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you don't want to have rows with the same id, and name then you can make both of them the primary key of table 'colleges' and then use insert ignore.

For making primary key use:

```
ALTER TABLE colleges
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, name);
```

Then use insert ignore like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO colleges (Id, Name, CreatedOn) 
VALUES ("20", "ASIET", "2017-12-14 06:44:32");
```